# Profile debug or release cuda code?

Tags: cuda, profiler, nvvp

I have been profiling an application with `nvprof and nvvp (5.5)` in order to optimize it. However, I get totally different results for some metrics/events like `inst_replay_overhead`, `ipc` or `branch_efficiency`, etc. when I'm profiling the debug (`-G`) and release version of the code.

**so my question is:** which version should I profile? The release or debug version? Or the choice depends upon what I'm looking for?

I found [CUDA - Visual Profiler and Control Flow Divergence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370325/cuda-visual-profiler-and-control-flow-divergence) where is stated that a debug (`-G`) version is needed to properly measure the divergent branches metric, but I am not sure about other metrics.

Comment: I don't see anything in the link you provided that says that -G is needed to properly measure the divergent branches metric.  That specific profiler feature being referred to (back-referencing to source) can be accomplished with either a release or debug version, as spelled out in the answer provided there.

Comment: Robert Crovella, you are correct. The source in the link gives two options, and i do not mention that. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Profiling usually implies that you care about performance.

If you care about performance, you should profile the release version of a CUDA code.

The debug version (-G) will generate different code, which usually runs slower.  There's little point in doing performance analysis (including execution time measurement, benchmarking, profiling, etc.) on a debug version of a CUDA code, in my opinion, for this reason.

The -G switch turns off most optimizations that the device code compiler might ordinarily make, which has a large effect on code generation and also often a large effect on performance.  The reason for the disabling of optimizations is to facilitate debug of code, which is the primary reason for the -G switch and for a debug version of your code.

Comment: In general you want to do a full release build. If you want to use source correlated experiments add -lineinfo. If you need to look at the logical control flow of the application -G can sometimes be more useful than -lineinfo. When using -G avoid looking at any other metrics.